# Parsing date from vb.net to web server(java)

Tags: vb.net, api, date, parsing, server

How can I parse this date `2019-06-27 00:00:00.000+0000` from `vb.net` to a web server ?

The error is as follows: `java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: 2019-06-27 00:00:00.000+0000`.

I already know that I have to parse it as: `yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss` but I don't know how to parse the `.000+0000` part. Maybe it is `GMT` or `UTC` ?

Answer (score 0):

the format for your set up will be hh:mm:ss.SSSSSS and set the timezone of simokedateformat to UTC.

Comment: Thank you for your reply but it didn't work either. I parsed it successfully from vb.net and the response was the same.